# EF6 not saving changes to related properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my application I decided to use EF6 instead of SQL connectors that i was used to. The problem is that when i use

```
 public MainDatabase() : base("Database")
    {
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

The Model class is

```
public class Hotel : BaseModel
{
    private City City = null;
    private HotelCategory HotelCategory;
    private string Name = string.Empty;
    private string Tel = string.Empty;
}
```

In my UnitOfWork I got a helper method

```
internal void SetState(BaseModel entity, EntityState state)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = state;
        _context.SaveChanges()
    }
```

It only saves changes to the strings and not the different index of related properties.

I use Code First and in my database

Is there any way to also update the state of related properties?

Tried this but didn't work

```
var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (var name in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            entry.Property(name).IsModified = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using UnitOfWork may cause you to missing scope. Therefore, you must include your entity object in db context

```
var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    var dbset = _context.Set<EntityType>();
    dbset.Attach(entity);
}

entry.state = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```